# JTable with custom JTableModel and it's errors

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I've written an app. with J2SE that uses JDBC and `JTable` to show some info. For fetching data into `JTable` I wrote a `JTableModel` and when I want to create a new `JTable`, I create a new instance of it to table's model too, when I open a form that contains `JTable`, no problem happens.  But when I open second form at same time, it raises an error:

```
Column count is out of range.
```

How may I solve it?

My code for jTableModel is like this :

```
public DBGrid(Connection conn, String Query) throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        connection= conn;

        statement= connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                              ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

        Connected= true;
        SetQuery(Query);
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlException)
    {                 
        sqlException.printStackTrace();
        Connected= false;
    }
}
```

and the code for creating inherit of model is this :

```
if(FormName.equals("Form1"))
    {
        if(CheckOpenForm("War_Group_Frame", "Groups"))
            return;

        DBGrid GridModel= new DBGrid(getDATABASE_URL(), getUserName(), getPassword(), 
                              "select *  from ware where Grp_ID= 0");
        War_Group_Frame W_F= new War_Group_Frame();

        W_F.WarList.setModel(GridModel);

        W_F.setVisible(true);
        Sender.add(W_F);
        BringFrameToFront(W_F);
    }
    else
    if(FormName.equals("Form2"))
    {
        if(CheckOpenForm("Ware_Unit", "Units"))
            return;

        Ware_Unit U_F= new Ware_Unit();                                                                                                                                                              
        U_F.UnitList.setModel(new DBGrid(connection, "select * from ware"));

        U_F.setVisible(true);
        Sender.add(U_F);
        BringFrameToFront(U_F);
    }
```

Error occors in this method of jTableModel Class :

```
public Class getColumnClass(int column) throws IllegalStateException
{
    if(!Connected)
        throw new IllegalStateException(java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("God_Lover/Resources").getString("DBNotConnectedError"));

    try
    {
        if(column< getColumnCount())
        {
            String ClassName = metaData.getColumnClassName(column + 1);
            return Class.forName(ClassName);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Object.class;
}
```

Comment: I've no earthly idea since you haven't told us anything that allows us to understand and debug your program, and my mind-reading abilities that would usually have allowed me to "see" your code have not been working since the last CT scan of my brain. I'm thinking of suing the radiologist.

Comment: Seriously though, without pertinent code, the chances of our ability to help you are on par with the Cubs winning the world series. This should be common sense, right?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, `count` was was incremented as rows were added to the first instance, but it was not reset for the second instance. You may not have noticed because the [default value](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) of an `int` instance variable is 0.